# Why does Array.prototype.sort put undefined values at the end?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-5

Why does the ECMAScript standard `Array.prototype.sort` insist on putting `undefined` values at the end of the array when specifying a `compareFn`? I would expect the `compareFn` to handle those accordingly and that it would have full control.

It does not matter which `compareFn` is used. The spec dictates this behavior before the `compareFn` is invoked.

[See the SortCompare abstract operation listing in the spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4.4.11), steps 10 thru 12.

As a proof of concept try running this:

```
var values = [undefined, undefined, 123];

values.sort(function(x, y) {
    console.log('compareFn called');
});
```

There will be no traces.

Comment: @Bergi it doesn't matter. look at the spec.

Comment: I would guess a possible reason is that most compare functions do *not* handle `undefined` accordingly…

Comment: If I had to gander a reason, by putting them at the end, once you've reached one, then you know that there aren't any more values.  If they were always placed at the front you would have to loop through the undefined until you found a value.  It's more efficient, because as soon as you find one you know there aren't any more values.

Comment: Interesting idd. The logic treating `undefined` as the *bigger* value. And Kevin has a point with reasoning. Combining this knowledge with how `Array.prototype.filter` works and we have a true WAT? moment.

Answer (score 2):

So your question is in fact **not**:

> Why does the ECMAScript standard Array.prototype.sort insist on
>   putting undefined values at the end of the array when specifying a
>   compareFn?

Because you answer it yourself: It's defined in the spec.

I can only guess and if I did I would guess your real question is:

> Why is the spec written as it is?

There is no true answer to this question but if I was to demand answer I would ping [BrendanEich](https://twitter.com/BrendanEich), [Rick Waldron](https://twitter.com/rwaldron) or any other TC39 member on twitter or sign up on the [es-discuss](http://www.ecmascript.org/community.php) mailing list.

Maybe if you had been a part of the community this *interesting feature* could have been avoided.